# js-data unsaved not returning objects with changes

Tags: jsdata

I have a user from my API in my js-data store and I changed it's name. I didn't save the record yet.

Why doesn't `ds.unsaved('user')` return an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unsaved()` function returns only records that have no id. No matter if they have changes or not.

According to the [docs](http://api.js-data.io/js-data/latest/Collection.html#unsaved)

> Return all "unsaved" (not uniquely identifiable) records in this colleciton.